# Cannot create native container on Windows

Tags: java, docker, windows-10, quarkus, graalvm

I want to create a native container for the getting-started quarkus application.
I get successful when I tried on Ubuntu, but for some reasons I am facing issues on Windows 10. Here is what I've tried so far.

I have no problem for creating a native executable with this command:

```
cmd /c 'call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" && mvn package -Pnative'
```

But when I try to create a native container with the command given in the [quarkus guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image):

```
cmd /c 'call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" && mvn package -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true'
```

I get the following errors:

```
Error: Invalid Path entry getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /project/getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
```

I've already checked my shared resources on Docker Desktop and I have C:\ and D:\ (which are my hard disks). So I don't know how to go further in the solution... Here is my entire stack if needed:

```
> cmd /c 'call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" && mvn package -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true'


**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.0
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< org.acme:getting-started >----------------------
[INFO] Building getting-started 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ getting-started ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ getting-started ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ getting-started ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\git\quarkus-quickstarts\getting-started\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ getting-started ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ getting-started ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running org.acme.getting.started.GreetingResourceTest
2020-05-17 16:25:01,839 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Quarkus 1.4.2.Final started in 1.350s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8081
2020-05-17 16:25:01,847 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile test activated.
2020-05-17 16:25:01,848 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, resteasy]
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.874 s - in org.acme.getting.started.GreetingResourceTest
2020-05-17 16:25:03,019 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Quarkus stopped in 0.030s
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ getting-started ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.4.2.Final:build (default) @ getting-started ---
[INFO] [org.jboss.threads] JBoss Threads version 3.1.1.Final
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.JarResultBuildStep] Building thin jar: D:\git\quarkus-quickstarts\getting-started\target\getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor] Quarkus augmentation completed in 850ms
[INFO]
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.4.2.Final:native-image (default) @ getting-started ---
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.JarResultBuildStep] Building native image source jar: D:\git\quarkus-quickstarts\getting-started\target\getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar\getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep] Building native image from D:\git\quarkus-quickstarts\getting-started\target\getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar\getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep] Pulling image quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:19.3.1-java11
19.3.1-java11: Pulling from quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image
Digest: sha256:9e2dd59c82db091bb90fd0ee60530291a5ecc201ebc718ffcc59ab0f406e47ea
Status: Image is up to date for quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:19.3.1-java11
quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:19.3.1-java11
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep] Running Quarkus native-image plugin on GraalVM Version 19.3.1 CE
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep] docker run -v //d/git/quarkus-quickstarts/getting-started/target/getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar:/project:z --env LANG=C --rm quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:19.3.1-java11 -J-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -J-Dsun.nio.ch.maxUpdateArraySize=100 -J-Dvertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxLogDelegateFactory -J-Dvertx.disableDnsResolver=true -J-Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=DISABLED -J-Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder=1 -J-Duser.language=fr -J-Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 --initialize-at-build-time= -H:InitialCollectionPolicy=com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.CollectionPolicy$BySpaceAndTime -H:+JNI -jar getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar -H:FallbackThreshold=0 -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces -H:-AddAllCharsets -H:-IncludeAllTimeZones -H:EnableURLProtocols=http -H:-UseServiceLoaderFeature -H:+StackTrace getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner
Error: Invalid Path entry getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /project/getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  11.752 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-17T16:25:09+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.4.2.Final:native-image (default) on project getting-started: Failed to generate native image: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]         [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep#build threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to build native image
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.build(NativeImageBuildStep.java:353)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:931)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Image generation failed. Exit code: 1
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.imageGenerationFailed(NativeImageBuildStep.java:369)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.build(NativeImageBuildStep.java:339)
[ERROR]         ... 12 more
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: What's your maven configuration to generate/packaging jar? As of now it's looking under the `project` folder. Without any explicit configuration the jar should be generated under the `target` directory.

Comment: I kept the original configuration of the getting-started project. I can see the generated jar under the `target` directory.

Comment: Did you checked this config:

`<configuration>
    <systemProperties>
<native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
</systemProperties>
</configuration>`

Comment: Yes this is what I have, and other variables seem correct. For example project.build.directory = ${project.basedir}/target. I made the same project works on ubuntu so I don't think there is this kind of issue. But I still don't know what's wrong.

Comment: If you want to plan running your app in the container anyway, then you can consider just building it in the container - look for "Creating a container with a multi-stage Docker build" in the page you are referring to. You dont have to setup all these C development tools, GraalVM, etc on your local machine. Whole compilation and build is done in the continers.

Comment: This is a good point (I also have issues with this multi-stage build, but this is another topic). The multi-stage build seems good for CI/CD, but I find it a waste to not benefit from my existing local setup. Furthermore if there is a real problem on Windows, it would be good to put it back in the documentation.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? Having the exact same issue at the moment.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I had to use Ubuntu. I think there is currently a real issue on Windows.

Comment: That's too bad, thanks for the update though.

Comment: @finstas Try to update your Docker Desktop to the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating `Docker Desktop for Windows` to the latest version ([2.3.0.3](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/#docker-desktop-community-2303)) fixed my issue.